# Prove that a composition of a borel function and a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

**Question:**
If $g$ is a Borel function and X is an RV, c is an atom of X. Prove that $\lbrace X=c\rbrace  \subseteq \lbrace g(X)=g(c)\rbrace $ .

**Thoughts:**
This was given as a part of a proof. I don't understand this passage, and not even the notation. Does this notation mean "Set of all Xs which are equal to c"?

Comment: This is just a property of the sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sometimes in such shorthand notation formality is beneficial. Recall that $X:\Omega\to \Bbb R$ and $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, so that
$$
  \{X = c\} = \{\omega\in \Omega:X(\omega) = c\},\quad \{g(X) = g(c)\} = \{\omega\in \Omega:g(X(\omega)) = g(c)\}.
$$
To show that the former is the subset of the latter, you need to show that if $\omega$ is an element of the former, then it is an element of the latter. That is, if $X(\omega) = c$ then $g(X(\omega)) = g(c)$ which is of course a trivial fact.

You can also do this on the level of inverse maps. That is, we need to show that $X^{-1}(c) \subseteq X^{-1}(A)$ where $A = g^{-1}(g(c))$. Notice that $c\in A$, and that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

With pedantic notations:
$$
\{
X = c
\} = 
\{\omega :
X(\omega) = c
\}\\
\{
g(X) = g(c)
\} = 
\{\omega :
g(X(\omega)) = g(c)
\}
$$

With these notations:
$$
[X(\omega) = c \implies g(X(\omega) )= g(c) ]
\\\implies \{
X = c
\} \subseteq \{
g(X) = g(c)
\} 
$$